# Send DELETE request to the external API

Tags: php, symfony

I have to send a DELETE request to the external cache API. How can I do that? I've been thinking about using `file()` function, like:

```
file('https://someurl.com/api?parameter1=foo&parameter2=bar');
```

But first of all it doesn't recognize the type of the response, and second it throws an error:

`Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in`...And it seems to convert ampersands into `&amp;` (at least that's what xdebug shows).

How can I solve this?

Comment: cURL seems to be the way.  I have a similar question using the YouTube API awaiting answer but you can see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482760/how-to-delete-a-youtube-video-using-curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cURL for that:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Ok...and what about the $result variable? What does it do? Does it already sends the request?

Comment: `curl_exec` has already sent the request. In the result you will have the body of response.